# How to fix background image issue

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, frontend, web-frontend

With this application, I'm having some imaging issues in terms of getting the background image to appear behind the login form. I'm currently using a bootstrap template in order to make this site. I tried posting the background image using the `.main-content`   div to no avail.

```
<div>
    <style>
        .main-content {
            background-image: url('../../../../wwwroot/images/MacbookBackground.jpg');
        }
    </style>
</div>
```

https://github.com/zhadjah9559/HelpDeskTicket/tree/3.LoginAndDB

Comment: Hi @Darnell,any updates about this case?

Comment: Me and a mentor have been working on setting up the DB as of late. When we get a sure fire way to fix it i will update. May have to create a new form and get rid of the 'animsition' class that the template uses

Comment: Have you tried my answer? Does it help you?

Comment: I did, Using the holder only showed for part of the area around the form. There is something about the way the template created the animsition class that is making it act like that. Will just cut out the classes and redo the form with the template's layout and hopefully it will work

Answer (score 2):

You can add your `<style>` in your `_Layout.cshtml` and your url should be `/images/MacbookBackground.jpg` , like below.

Your `_Layout.cshtml` head:

```
<head>
//...
<style>
    .main-content {
        background-image: url('/images/MacbookBackground.jpg');
    }
</style>
</head>
```

Then in your view:

```
<div class="main-content">
<h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
</div>
```

Result:
[image]